# Blen4web and Alembic animation not playing

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, blend-files, blend4web

I created alembic files from different 3d software (from iclone type ogawa for Blender).

When I import the **alembic** file into Blender 2.78 (together with the blend4web SDK latest release) and play the timeline the animation runs smoothly, but when exporting the scene the *json or html* files do not play the animation.

**The Problem**

How do I transfer the animations from **alembic** to mesh so it can be played after the scene is exported in ***json/bin*** or ***html*** format ?

I also tried using an add-on, but it didn't work. Here is the link to [animation jointer](http://www.coyhot.com/blender-addon-amination-joiner/).

It helps joining all the animations in one and creates keyframes per frame animated plus other features.

Comment: I'm not totally sure if this is even supported by Blend4Web at all. As far as I know Alembic is an external caching system. It uses separate mesh files for each frame animation, as an external file. Not sure this kind of data could be exported to web formats, and even if it did it would be a huge file, containing loads of mesh data, one for each frame. Even if it even played in a browser, performance would probably be abysmal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Monster it looks like is a huge file I actually came across a plugin that join the animations into one mesh and then I do a vertex bake to embed  the animation into the scene, but it takes quiet long in my ppc to bake just 100 frames... still experimenting, but it's there a way to transform the cache animation from the alembic to a skeletal or something less heavy to animate?? or animating many bake animations at the same time?

Comment: I guess you want to thank  Duarte Farrajota Ramos rather than me :).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try baking your vertex animation with this dedicated tool available in Blend4Web:
https://www.blend4web.com/doc/en/animation.html#vertex-animation
See also this tutorial:
https://www.blend4web.com/en/community/article/48/

Comment: Thanks yes I actually use this tool to bake it thank you